# Online retailers for brown nipper bottles (187 mL)?

Tags: bottles, conditioning

I like using nipper bottles for high-alcohol brews as well using a few in each batch I bottle so I can test carbonation levels & flavors as the batch bottle conditions.

So far, I've only had luck finding green and clear bottles.  Are there any online retailers that sell brown nipper bottles?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but in a word, no.  187 ml bottles are made for the wine industry and they only come in clear or green.  If they are available they are beyond my Google-fu.

But there is a non-traditional amber [8oz or 4oz alternative from herbal medicine manufacturers](http://www.herbco.com/c-8-glassware.aspx) that go for about a $1.00 to $1.35 per.  They should do the job for you, even if they are a little odd.  I don't know anything else about these bottles, I have never used them myself.  My only concern would be their thickness in respect to withstanding carbonation pressures.  It probably wouldn't be a problem and they are cheap enough to order a few and give them a try.

Personally, I would just short-fill a couple of regular bottles and CO2 purge them.

Answer (score 1):

You could start drinking those new mini Rogue bottles (7 oz.) and re-use them:

http://beernews.org/2009/12/rogue-ales-moving-xs-line-including-new-mcrogue-scotch-ale-to-7-oz-bottles/

At $3.75 per bottle (here in NH), it'd be expensive, but it's damn good beer.

Answer (score 0):

You could get some clear bottles and spray paint them, which would make them skunk-proof and awesome looking.

I've been thinking about doing this for a while, although haven't tried it yet so can't offer any specific advice. If you wanted to get fancy you could use tape or adhesive-backed vinyl sheets to create a two-tone pattern, and then give the bottle a coat of clear finish to make it durable.

Comment: paint often has a tough time adhering to nice shiny glass.

Comment: Good point. There must be a way though. Stone and Delirium paint their bottles.